# Understanding Nslookup root=NAME

Tags: windows-10, dns, nslookup

Good day, the task to describe what makes the parameter Root nslookup utility.

The problem is that when I try to change something with the aid of this parameter, then get back "Unrecognized commands""

[image: problems]

What I'm doing wrong and how to demonstrate the operation of this parameter?

Comment: Did you try quoting the server? Example: set root="a.root-servers.net"

Comment: yes I tried 
[link](https://postimg.org/image/lwiap83vx/)

Comment: I posted an answer, try it to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What I'm doing wrong

You need to remove the spaces around the `=`:

```
> nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> set root=a.root-servers.net
> ...
> exit
```

---

#### Print info on common commands

```
> ?
Commands:   (identifiers are shown in uppercase, [] means optional)
NAME            - print info about the host/domain NAME using default server
NAME1 NAME2     - as above, but use NAME2 as server
help or ?       - print info on common commands
set OPTION      - set an option
    all                 - print options, current server and host
    [no]debug           - print debugging information
    [no]d2              - print exhaustive debugging information
    [no]defname         - append domain name to each query
    [no]recurse         - ask for recursive answer to query
    [no]search          - use domain search list
    [no]vc              - always use a virtual circuit
    domain=NAME         - set default domain name to NAME
    srchlist=N1[/N2/.../N6] - set domain to N1 and search list to N1,N2, etc.
    root=NAME           - set root server to NAME
    retry=X             - set number of retries to X
    timeout=X           - set initial time-out interval to X seconds
    type=X              - set query type (ex. A,AAAA,A+AAAA,ANY,CNAME,MX,NS,PTR,SOA,SRV)
    querytype=X         - same as type
    class=X             - set query class (ex. IN (Internet), ANY)
    [no]msxfr           - use MS fast zone transfer
    ixfrver=X           - current version to use in IXFR transfer request
server NAME     - set default server to NAME, using current default server
lserver NAME    - set default server to NAME, using initial server
root            - set current default server to the root
ls [opt] DOMAIN [> FILE] - list addresses in DOMAIN (optional: output to FILE)
    -a          -  list canonical names and aliases
    -d          -  list all records
    -t TYPE     -  list records of the given RFC record type (ex. A,CNAME,MX,NS,PTR etc.)
view FILE           - sort an 'ls' output file and view it with pg
exit            - exit the program
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [nslookup](http://ss64.com/nt/nslookup.html) - Lookup IP addresses on a NameServer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem. For some reason the set doesn't seem to work write when you're already in the nslookup command prompt.

What you should do is quit the nslookup program and then from a regular command prompt use the command:

```
nslookup /set root=yourserver.example.com
```

This should fix your issue. It did for me anyways.

Comment: "For some reason the set doesn't seem to work write when you're already in the nslookup command prompt." wrong. See my answer.